# Reparametrize posterior - from $\text{Beta}(2, 2)$ prior to $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, beta-distribution

My posterior distribution
$$
p(\theta\mid y) \propto p(y \mid \theta) p(\theta)
$$
has a prior $p(\theta)$ that is a $\text{Beta}(2, 2)$ rescaled between $(0, 10)$. I don't want my parameter to be constrained, so I want to write it in terms of an *unconstrained* parameter $\vartheta$, preferably with prior $p(\vartheta)=\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ such that I can write (using the change of variables formula)
$$
p(\vartheta \mid y) \propto p(y \mid f^{-1}(\vartheta)) p(f^{-1}(\vartheta))|J_f(\vartheta)|
$$
where $f$ is a transformation that transforms $\vartheta\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ into $\theta$.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions.  Only one is continuous and monotonically increasing, though: the [probability integral transform.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=probability+integral+transform)  This is the simplest case of the solutions given in the duplicate.

Comment: @whuber I'm confused. The link to point to talks about densities that are everywhere non-zero, but this is not the case for the Beta distribution here

Comment: Although that's correct, I was hoping it would be obvious that the method would apply without change to your situation.  To be explicit, with $F$ the Beta$(2,2)$ distribution and $G$ the standard Normal distribution, the function $G^{-1}(F(\theta/10))$ is defined on the interval $(0,10)$ and converts any Beta$(2,2)$ variable into a standard Normal variable.